# Android design icons for different screens

Tags: android, user-interface

I have a question regarding designing icons to use in my application. I've made a design in Photoshop based on 720x1280p (my current phone screen res).

Now I want to create my app but I wonder what would be the best strategy to design icons for all screensize's and ratios?

I've made an app before this one a time ago and I still remeber how many time I had to resize my icons for the different screens (hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi, xhpdi, ...). Also when the screen ratio's changed I had to change my icons to and it was a little bit frustrating (a lot actually!).

So this time I want to try this the proper way but what is the proper way? Can i create SVG icons that automatically fit every screensize? Should I create one big icon and let Android to the resizing or should I stick with the frustrating method of resizing every icon a thousand times?